# Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' error when trying require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, stripe-payments

Trying to get Stripe library up and running. Get failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' error.

autoload.php is there in /vendor

ran composer update, then composer install , didn't help.

**config.php**

```
    <?php

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

    $stripe = array(
      "secret_key"      => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "publishable_key" => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    );

    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);

?>
```

**autoload.php**

```
<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

    require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

    return ComposerAutoloaderInit18eff69591fc6597a849a05ec4932261::getLoader();
```

Comment: Why require autoload? Add namespace and `use Stripe/Stripe` versus the include...no?

Comment: is it a laravel project?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a problem with your relative path. Because this *"script is in `/app/modules/stripe`"* and the vendor folder *"is `/vendor`"*, then you can use the constant `__DIR__` to reference the included script's location, and then up 3 relative directories.

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/../../../vendor/autoload.php');
```

Comment: Definitely not in the same directory. script is in /app/modules/stripe, the vendor folder is /vendor

Comment: @LaserBeak well that's why it's not including, your path is wrong. I've updated my answer with the relative path

Answer (score 1):

try this.Work for me.

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the require_once to this:

`require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: I actually [already proposed](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37908552/revisions) this answer, see the comments why it didn't work.

Comment: oh okay. @JeffPuckettII